# List full home directory using php on mac os 10.8.2

Tags: php, directory, osx-mountain-lion

I wrote a php script to output the content of a directory. It works perfectly with "/usr/local/" for example but impossible to run the same code with "/Users/der_/Pictures/"...
The output is: "Failed opening directory /Users/der_/Pictures/ for reading". Checking the permissions for this directory give: owner -der_, group -staff. Thanks.
running php 5.4.6...
Is it necessary to change permissions to "root"?
My answer is "yes": change the directory permissions i.e. chown user:group myexemple_directory but be careful...

Answer (score 0):

A user profile should NOT have root permissions

This one works for me

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/Users/der_/Pictures')) {
    echo "Content:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```